# how to post an image from url with tkinter while in def function

Tags: python, tkinter

the title of my question was probably pretty confusion but I don't know how to word it any better.

basically when i put my code in the def for a button command, it doesn't work, but the code works outside of the def just fine.

this is the code that doesn't work:

```
app = Tk()
app.geometry("1000x800")

def search():
    tx1get = tx1.get()
    Label(app, text="You Entered: \"" + tx1get + "\"").grid(row=1, column=0)
    fd = urllib.urlopen("http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTc2MTU4ODI5MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODI2MzAyOA@@._V1_SY317_CR7,0,214,317_AL_.jpg")
    imgFile = io.BytesIO(fd.read())
    im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imgFile))
    image = Label(app, image = im, bg = "blue")
    image.grid(row=2, column=0)

tx1=StringVar()
tf = Entry(app, textvariable=tx1, width="100")
b1 = Button(app, text="Search", command=search, width="10")
tf.grid(row=0, column=0)
b1.grid(row=0, column=1)

app.mainloop()
```

However if I remove the last 5 lines in the def and put them outside the def, it works:

```
app = Tk()
app.geometry("1000x800")

def search():
    tx1get = tx1.get()
    Label(app, text="You Entered: \"" + tx1get + "\"").grid(row=1, column=0)

tx1=StringVar()
tf = Entry(app, textvariable=tx1, width="100")
b1 = Button(app, text="Search", command=search, width="10")
tf.grid(row=0, column=0)
b1.grid(row=0, column=1)

fd = urllib.urlopen("http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTc2MTU4ODI5MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODI2MzAyOA@@._V1_SY317_CR7,0,214,317_AL_.jpg")
imgFile = io.BytesIO(fd.read())
im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imgFile))
image = Label(app, image = im, bg = "blue")
image.grid(row=2, column=0)

app.mainloop()
```

any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work, because `im` in `search` goes out of scope once `search` completes. With this, your ImageTk object disappears as well. To prevent this, make `im` global (one possible solution):

```
import urllib 
from Tkinter import *
import io
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


app = Tk()
app.geometry("1000x800")

im = None  #<-- im is global

def search():
    global im  #<-- declar im as global, so that you can write to it
               # not needed if you only want to read from global variable.
    tx1get = tx1.get()
    Label(app, text="You Entered: \"" + tx1get + "\"").grid(row=1, column=0)
    fd = urllib.urlopen("http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTc2MTU4ODI5MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODI2MzAyOA@@._V1_SY317_CR7,0,214,317_AL_.jpg")
    imgFile = io.BytesIO(fd.read())
    im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imgFile))
    image = Label(app, image = im, bg = "blue")
    image.grid(row=2, column=0)

tx1=StringVar()
tf = Entry(app, textvariable=tx1, width="100")
b1 = Button(app, text="Search", command=search, width="10")
tf.grid(row=0, column=0)
b1.grid(row=0, column=1)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Nice. thanks marcin!